# Delete file from server using UTL_FILE.FRemove without knowing the file name

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, wildcard, utl-file

I am a reporting analyst, who was asked to learn some PL/SQL to automate some processes.  So I am almost finished, with one step standing in the way. I have a package that

1. Loads a table with a query I wrote.
2. Exports the results from that table to a .txt file on the server with the     current_date tacked onto the file name .

I am trying to delete the 3 files it creates using a wildcard, but I continually get errors such as "vendor_file.ia.*.txt is not defined":

- file_location is my path

I can delete it no problem with:

```
    utl_file.fremove(file_location,'vendor_file.ia.09.02.2015.txt');
    utl_file.fremove(file_location,'vendor_file.il.09.02.2015.txt');
    utl_file.fremove(file_location,'vendor_file.sd.09.02.2015.txt');
```

But obviously that won't delete it when it gets run next month. So am I missing a simple wildcard to search just for 'vendor_file.ia.*' And does the syntax look in Oracle?

If I didn't provide enough information please let me know!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'd have to know the exact file name in order to call `fremove`.  You can't pass a wild card.  If you don't mind some hackery (particularly relying on `x$` tables) you can use `dbms_backup_restore` to list the files in a directory https://davidalejomarcos.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/how-to-list-files-on-a-directory-from-oracle-database/  Or you can use a Java stored procedure https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584

Comment: My solution would be to create a table with two fields 1) filename, 2) deleted_flag.  Write the file-name to this table when it is created and then when you are ready to delete the file look for any filenames that are not marked as deleted and delete them and mark the record as deleted in the table.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson - or just a table with filename in it. Delete the row in the table when the file is deleted.

Comment: @BobJarvis that would work to, I would just lean towards having an audit, so that I can see what files have been created / deleted, for debugging / tracing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, fellas! I am going to try and make the table with the name. The hackery might be out of my skill set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old post but...

You can make an external table list out a directory file contents.
You could then write a loop to get your files names from the external table and execute utl_file.fremove

Answer (score 4):

This can be used to clear multiple files from the Oracle directory:

```sql
begin
    for i in (
        select filename from (select * from 
    table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DIR_NAME')) order by mtime) where filename like 
    'backup%')
    loop
        UTL_FILE.FREMOVE ('DIR_NAME', i.filename );
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Note: `RDSADMIN` is an AWS package, so it only makes sense in RDS, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the preprocessor to run a shell script to delete the files.
[Oracle docs on preprocessor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-73A6DA8D-EA78-4B9B-BAB3-0C99BF190A50.htm#SUTIL1385)

Answer (score -1):

How we schedule this script using Oracle scheduler:

```
 begin
    for i in (select filename from (select * from 
    table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DIR_NAME')) order by mtime) where filename like 
    'backup%')
    loop
    UTL_FILE.FREMOVE ('DIR_NAME', i.filename );
    end loop;
    end;
    /
```

Comment: This answer is already posted by @pankaj